# Flask view with parameter not loading css

Tags: python, flask

I get this weird issue.

I defined my Flask like the following:

```
blog = Blueprint(
    'blog',
    __name__,
    template_folder='templates',
    static_folder='static'
)
@blog.route("/post")

def post():
    return render_template('post.html')
```

The `http://localhost:5000/blog/post` loads the css correctly, however, if I added a parameter to the `post()`, the css can not be loaded.

```
@blog.route("/post/<fileid>")
def post(fileid):
    page = download_file_from_google_drive(fileid)
    page = Markup(markdown.markdown(page))
    return render_template('post.html', page)
```

The `post.html` uses the template. and looks like the following:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}


{% block content %}

    <!-- Page Header -->
    <header class="masthead" style="background-image: url('static/img/post-bg.jpg')">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-10 mx-auto">
            <div class="post-heading">
              <h1>Man must explore, and this is exploration at its greatest</h1>
              <h2 class="subheading">Problems look mighty small from 150 miles up</h2>
              <span class="meta">Posted by
                <a href="#">Start Bootstrap</a>
                on August 24, 2017</span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </header>

    <!-- Post Content -->
    <article>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-10 mx-auto">

            {{ page }}

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </article>

    <hr>

{% endblock %}
```

Is there something wrong with my BluePrint set up?

Comment: Can't saw the css  load statement in your template file.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong with your Python code at all.

However, looks like you are loading CSS using relative path to the current page, which implies that if you are on the page with the URL = `/blog/post/<fileid>`, your CSS (well, anything, whose path is specified relative to the current path) gets loaded like this: `/blog/post/<fileid>/<whatever>`.

You should try loading your CSS using absolute path. That would look like this: `/post.css`.

So, the only thing you need to change is your `base.html` template.

If this is not solving your problem, open the developer console and look at the output. If you are smart enough, you can figure the answer yourself.